# How to plot a discrete variable against another discrete variable in Julia?

Tags: plot, julia, data-science

Suppose I have a database consisting of two columns, the first one corresponding to the gender of the respondent and the second one to the field he or she is studying.
This table comes from importing a csv file using the CSV library.

```
Gender,Field
Male,Physics
Female,Physics
Female,Mathematics
Male,Physics
Male,Physics
Male,Physics
Female,Mathematics
Female,Mathematics
Male,Physics
```

```
using CSV

data = CSV.read("data.csv")
```

Using Julia, I would like to represent this database in the form of a histogram **grouped** by one of these characters.

I have searched several libraries but being new to the language, I have not found a practical method.

Comment: Have you taken the tutorial? https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/tutorial/

Comment: Of course I did but it does not contain any solution to my problem.

Comment: It sounds like you want to plot a bar graph, not a histogram, because histograms depict quantitative data while you want to represent qualitative data (i.e., subjects). Try using [Gadfly](https://maidens.github.io/jekyll/update/2016/11/23/Tufte-Bar-Chart-Julia.html) in Julia.

Comment: Well, the link you're giving me isn't a **grouped** histogram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using Plots (http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/basics/)

```
using CSV, Plots
using StatsBase: countmap

data = CSV.read("data.csv")

genders = unique(data[!, :Gender])
categories = unique(data[!, :Field])

cm = countmap(Tuple.(eachrow(data)))
# Dict{Tuple{String,String},Int64} with 3 entries:
# ("Female", "Mathematics") => 3
# ("Female", "Physics")     => 1
# ("Male", "Physics")       => 5

# With Plots you can pass a Matrix to plot multiple series
# each column is a series and each row is a category
y = [get(cm, (g, c), 0) for c in categories, g in genders]
# 2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
# M  F
# 5  1 Physics
# 0  3 Mathematics

# We want each label to apply to a series,
# so instead of an n-length Vector, we pass a 1xn Matrix.
labels = permutedims(genders) 
# 1×2 Array{String,2}:
# "Male"  "Female"

bar(categories, y, labels = labels)
```

[image]